# masking a portion of a control in wpf

Tags: wpf

Is it possible for me to mask a portion of a control in WPF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't really give a lot of detail, but I'm guessing that you want part of a control to be transparent.

Probably the best way to do that is to modify the control template of that control.  That gives you complete, er, control over the appearance of that control.

To get the base ControlTemplate of any control, you can either use Expression Blend or XamlWriter to do so - here is a [good link](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/wpf-kid-stuff-extracting) that explains both fairly simple procedures.

I don't know what kind of control that you are interested in.  Some are fairly simple, some fairly complex, and a majority are in between.  Just be careful if you see a control in the template named "PART_something".  These are required, and a bit of WPF black magic to make certain controls work automatically.

Comment: I actually cannot modify the control template which is why I want to mask a portion of it. sort of like the reverse of clipping

Comment: Why can't you modify the control template?  The reason I ask is, all controls have a modifiable control template.